# ora-03113 - end of file on communication channel

Tags: oracle

I am facing issue with Oracle 11g databases. Whenever I am running a long query in through Oracle SQL developer or application, it's through error ora-03113 end of file on communication channel.

I have checked database sga size and set the correct database sid. 
Please suggest and configuration change required to solve this problem.

Comment: `ora-03113` is a generic error hurled when an Oracle bug causes the session to terminate. The root cause could be any number of things. The Alert log will have more information and there may be a trace file too. Please look have a look at the files. If you don't know where to find them, the location is given by `show parameter background_dump_dest`. If you don't know how to solve the problem after reading the files please **edit your question** with more information.

Comment: While it always worth looking into alert.log and trace files, I would say that in most cases when I faced this error I ended up tweaking parts of the query, running parts of the query separately, applying hints, checking and comparing plans, etc.   If Oracle optimizer chokes on your complex query, changing database parameters in most cases will do nothing.